# Deleting a specific S3 objects based on JSON data inside the object

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a use-case to delete specific S3 files based on a key value.

The S3 location contains multiple nested json files, which has mainly 3 columns `header,body,created_timestamp`. The field `body` is nested. In the first level there is a tag `employee` and second level it contains attributes of employee like `ID,name` etc.

I want to delete all the json files from this S3 path where ID is `101`. How I can implement this using pyspark?

Comment: Please narrow down your problem  to a very specific problem and show also what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi - follow this documentation url - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html

Comment: Specific file -  DELETE /my-third-image.jpg?versionId=UIORUnfndfiufdisojhr398493jfdkjFJjkndnqUifhnw89493jJFJ HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 1):

There is an Amazon S3 feature called [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html) that can execute SQL statements against a *single* object in Amazon S3. The SQL statement can query the contents of the object without needing to download the object to your computer. It can also interpret JSON within the object.

Therefore, you could write a program that does the following:

- Loops through each object in a given path (directory)
- Calls S3 Select to retrieve the `body.employee.ID` element from the JSON
- If it matches the desired value, call `DeleteObject()` to delete that object from the S3 bucket

Alternatively, if the format is not compatible with S3 Select, you would need to write a program that downloads each object, checks its contents and then optionally deletes the object.